# Image OnLoad Server

Tags: javascript, image, onload-event

Please can someone help, I am converting an svg xml to image and then on image onload event converts this to an actual dataURI. This works perfectly on my local host, but when deployed to the server, I noticed that onload event never gets fired again. This works fine in all browsers locally, but when deployed to the server does not work in Chrome and Safari This is the snippet

```
var imgString = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(sourceSVG)));
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var imageSelected = $('.highImage');
if (section == "high") {
imageSelected = $('.lowImage');
}
imageSelected.find('img').attr({ 'src': img, 'height': '100%', 'width': '100%' });
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 0;
canvas.height = 0;
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
$('#' + targetCanvas).css({ 'height': 0, 'width': 0 });
};

image.src = "";
image.src = imgString;
```

Can someone please help me, its driving me nuts

Comment: Any error log in your browser debugger console?

Comment: Just a wild guess but I once had a problem with svg where it turned out the mime type `image/svg+xml` was not configured on the server.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but this works on other browsers on the same server

Comment: @isim, No error. It just doesn't fire up the image.onLoad event

Comment: If I recall correctly, some Object Properties like `.onload` still don't work properly. Perhaps do it the old fashion way like: `image.setAttribute('onload',function(){});` Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks Brendan, tried that which is a massive step forward at least it now calls into the event, however it generated a transparent background

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your help, after much debugging, I figured out that the problem was this line of code that i used in pulling down the svg file         xhr.send(); Suprisingly, the function that loads the image was called twice, I had to change         xhr.send() to         xhr.send(null)